Graph of a quadratic function with CanvasRenderingContext2D
I have a task in which I would like to implement the graphical visualisation of a quadratic equation in the interval x =[-10,10] and - if any exist - the corresponding zeros, using CanvasRenderingContext2D methods.
To convert the coordinates into pixel coordinates within the canvas I would use following functions:
var toCanvasX = function(x) { 

return (x +(max-min)/2)*canvas.width/(max-min);

} 

var toCanvasY = function(y) { 

return canvas.height-(y+(max-min)/2)*canvas.height/(max-min)

} 

The graph should look like this:
pic1
pic2
How could I solve it?
Code:
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 

<head> 

    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 

    <h1>Solver of Quadratic Equations</h1> 

    <script> 

        var a, b, c; 

        var output; 

         
        function check() {      

            a = document.forms["input_form"]["anumber"].value; 

            b = document.forms["input_form"]["bnumber"].value; 

            c = document.forms["input_form"]["cnumber"].value; 


            if (a == 0) { 

                output = "a cannot equal zero!"; 

            } else if (isNaN(a)) { 

                output = "a has to be a number!"; 

            } else if (isNaN(b)) { 

                output = "b has to be a number!"; 

            } else if (isNaN(c)) { 

                output = "c has to be a number!"; 

            } else { 

                var x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a); 

                var x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a); 

                output = "The polynomial <strong>" + (a == 1 ? "" : a) + "x\u00B2 + " + (b == 1 ? "" : b) + "x + " + c + " = 0</strong> has two zeros x1=" + x1 + "," + " " + "x2=" + x2; 

            } 

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output; 

        } 

    </script> 

</head> 

<body>
 

This programme calculates zeros of quadratic polynomials of the form ax² + bx + c and graphically displays the solution in the interval x ∈ [-10,10].
<br><br> 

<form name="input_form" action="javascript:check();"> 

    a: <input type="text" name="anumber" required> 

    b: <input type="text" name="bnumber" required> 

    c: <input type="text" name="cnumber" required> 

    <br><br> 

    <input type="submit" value="Calculate zeros"> 

</form> 

<p id="output"/> 


Can you fix your formatting please? This is difficult to read.

I don't know where your two functions toCanvasX(x) and toCanvasY(y) get it's x and y respectively parameters from - nor where min and max are computed anyway but to draw a graph from a quadratic equation you need to evaluate it at several different values of ‍x. The result of this calculation is the y coordinate of the graph for a specific x value.
As you're interested in an interval of [-10,10] it's as simple as looping from -10 to 10 in relatively small steps, e.g. 0.1:
for (let x = -10; x < 10; x += 0.1) {
}

and inside this for-loop use the x variable to calculate y. Both variables are then used with the CanvasRenderingContext2D's lineTo(x,y) method to draw the actual graph.
Here's an example:


let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
let a = 1;
let b = 3;
let c = 2;
let y;
context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
context.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);
context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.strokeStyle = "#5ead5e";
context.beginPath();
let scale = 30;
for (let x = -10; x < 10; x += 0.1) {
  y = (-1) * ((a * (x * x)) + (b * x) + c);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2 + x * scale, canvas.height / 2 + y * scale);
}
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
let x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
let x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);

context.beginPath();
context.arc(canvas.width / 2 + x1 * scale, canvas.height / 2, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(canvas.width / 2 + x2 * scale, canvas.height / 2, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.closePath();



